# Inserting time delays between send_keys requests in Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My initial problem is that when I get the `page_source` of a website page that I want to scrape, I don't have access to all the code because the full code only loads if I scroll through the different boxes on the site.

I decided to use the `send_keys` method in Selenium to press the "TAB" key multiple times to go through all the elements on the website page and to load the full code.

But when using the following, the "TAB" key is pressed to rapidly, so the code does not load:

```
browser.find_element(by=By.ID,value='multi-selector-checkbox-ember44').send_keys(Keys.TAB * 500)
```

I tried using a time.sleep function to add time delays between each `send_keys(Keys.TAB)` repetition, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution: on the page website, there are buttons of class 'small-input' at every level, so I used this function to scroll down the page:

```
    def scroll_down(self):
        to_explore = browser.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME,value='small-input')
        for i in range(len(to_explore)):
            to_explore[i].send_keys((Keys.TAB)*2)
            time.sleep(.5)
```